# How to compare a row with another rows with similar value in same dataframe and set value to new column

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv dataset like this

Visit ID | Visit Date| ID Number | Diagnosis | Panel | GP TO SP |

1. 001| 1/1/2021  |     1001  |   Psoriasis |    Panel GP
2. 002| 2/1/2021  |   1002    |   Back Pain, Joint Pain   | Panel GP
3. 003| 2/1/2021  |  1003     |   Fever         |Panel GP
4. 004| 4/1/2021  | 1001      |   Psoriasis      |Panel SP
5. 005| 8/1/2021  | 1004      |Joint Paint    |Panel GP
6. 006| 9/1/2021  |1005       |Joint Paint    |Panel GP
7. 007| 10/1/2021 |1002       | Back Pain     |Panel SP

I need to assign a new value GP to SP, indicating follow-up from the general clinic to the specialist. First I'll order by the dataset by ID Number and date. Then how can I compare each row with another rows that have same id number so that I can figure out if there's any row that has same diagnosis (Specialist) which previous row (same ID but older visit date, panel GP)

*Edited

def gp_to_sp(g):
return (
(g['Diagnosis'] == g['diagnosis'].shift()) &
(g['Panel'] == 'Panel SP') &
(g['Panel'].shift() == 'Panel GP')
)

newdf = df.assign(gp_to_sp=df.groupby('HashedNRIC').apply(gp_to_sp).droplevel(0))

This code is working but with this code, the GP to SP for Patient with ID (1002) will be false although it should be true because the diagnosis is not exactly matched as he only visits SP for one of the diagnoses in GP (back pain).

Plus is it possible to assign new column GP_referral that will record which visit ID resulting in GP_to_SP True condition? For example, Row 4 will have GP_referral value (001)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** the modified question now has possibly multiple diagnoses per row. In that case, we want to first `explode()` this column. In addition, the initial `Visit ID` is requested. As such, we can simplify and just have a `referral_id` that is `NaN` when there are no referrals, or the initial visit ID when it is a "GP to SP" referral.

Let's start with a **reproducible example**:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Visit ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    'Visit Date': ['2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-04-01',
                   '2021-08-01', '2021-09-01', '2021-10-01'],
    'ID Number': [1001, 1002, 1003, 1001, 1004, 1005, 1002],
    'Diagnosis': ['Psoriasis', 'Back Pain, Joint Pain', 'Fever', 'Psoriasis',
                  'Joint Paint', 'Joint Paint', 'Back Pain'],
    'Panel': ['Panel GP', 'Panel GP', 'Panel GP', 'Panel SP',
              'Panel GP', 'Panel GP', 'Panel SP']})
df['Visit Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Visit Date'])
```

And now:

```py
def referral_id(g):
    p = g['Panel']
    isref = (p == 'Panel GP').shift() & (p == 'Panel SP')
    return g['Visit ID'].shift().loc[isref]

z = df.assign(
    Diagnosis=df['Diagnosis'].str.split(r'\s*,\s*', regex=True)
).explode('Diagnosis').sort_values('Visit Date')

dfnew = df.assign(referral_id=z.groupby(['ID Number', 'Diagnosis'], as_index=False, group_keys=False).apply(referral_id))

>>> dfnew
   Visit ID Visit Date  ID Number Diagnosis              Panel      referral_id
0  1        2021-01-01  1001                   Psoriasis  Panel GP  NaN        
1  2        2021-02-01  1002       Back Pain, Joint Pain  Panel GP  NaN        
2  3        2021-02-01  1003                       Fever  Panel GP  NaN        
3  4        2021-04-01  1001                   Psoriasis  Panel SP  1.0        
4  5        2021-08-01  1004                 Joint Paint  Panel GP  NaN        
5  6        2021-09-01  1005                 Joint Paint  Panel GP  NaN        
6  7        2021-10-01  1002                   Back Pain  Panel SP  2.0
```

Comment: Thank you. It works! 

By the way is there any ways to code so that the statement g['Diagnosis'] == g['Diagnosis'].shift() can be true even when only part of diagnosis is equal? 

Because right now there's  a row with multiple diagnosis for visit in GP (fever, joint paint) and the follow up in SP only for one diagnosis (fever).

Comment: Done. Thank you for the help Pierre. I am not familiar with python but need to use it for one of my tasks. Really appreciate your help!